# Ошибка "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть бегунок, при "драге которого" должны последовательно чекаться чекбоксы.
Но почему-то при добавлении метода

```
.attr({
    checked: 'checked'
})
```

пишет

> is not a function

Сам бегунок создан с помощью noUISlider (используются некоторые методы для реализации).

```
<div id="range"></div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_1</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_2</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_3</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_4</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_5</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_6</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_7</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_8</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_9</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_10</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_11</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_12</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_13</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_14</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_15</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_16</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_17</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_18</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_19</span></label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test_20</span></label>
</div>

<div id="see"></div>
```

JS

```
var startSlider = document.getElementById('range');
var maxCount = $('.wrapper > label');

noUiSlider.create(startSlider, {
    start: 1,
    step: 1,
    range: {
        'min': [  0 ],
        'max': [ maxCount.length ]
    },
    format: {
      to: function ( value ) {
        return value;
      },
      from: function ( value ) {
        return value.replace(',-', '');
      }
    }
});


var stepSliderValueElement = document.getElementById('see');

var checkbox = maxCount.children('input');

startSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    stepSliderValueElement.innerHTML = values[handle];
    var i = values[handle];
    // var countCheck = checkbox[i];


    if(checkbox.eq(i).is(':checked')){
        checkbox.eq(i).removeAttr('checked');
    }else{
        checkbox.eq(i).attr( "checked", 'checked');
    }


    console.log(checkbox[i]);
});
```

Почему методы для checkbox[i] not a function.
Подскажите плиз, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что `checkbox[i]` это не *jQuery* объект, а *HTMLElement*, и у него действительно нет такой функции.

Для решения можете использовать [*eq*](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
checkbox.eq(i).attr({
    checked: 'checked'
});
```

Comment: Можно, кстати, ещё упомянуть, что при смене одного атрибута достаточно использовать `attr("checked", 'checked')`. И второе, главное: использование атрибута `checked` для изменения состояния `checkbox` - плохой подход.

Comment: Круто, работает,

Comment: А подскажите, чтобы когда бегунок уходил в обратную сторону чекбоксы становились неотмеченными.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: @mangoloid1, например удалять этот атрибут с помощью [_removeAttr_](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/),  или менять соответствующее свойство: [_prop_](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: Сделал, так.
Но не помогло удалять атрибут "checked"
Как это можно решить.

Comment: @mangoloid1, что вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: Работает, но с поправкой, что доходя до последнего он его чекает но не убирает чек с текущего когда слайдер идет назад.
Как это можно решить?

Comment: @mangoloid1 используйте _prop_, в любом случае этот вопрос не относится к ранее заданному. Так что задайте его отдельным вопросом

Comment: **checked** - это больше свойство. Поэтому с ним надо работать соответствующим методом, а именно .prop(). `$(element).prop('checked', true); // отметить ` `$(element).prop('checked', false); // снять галку`